# Magento 2: New Linux Operating System Vulnerability

Tags: magento2, security, server-setup, linux

https://magento.com/security/vulnerabilities/new-linux-operating-system-vulnerability

> If you manage your own server, you will need to update the kernel (and
>   reboot your server) once the security patch is issued by your
>   operating system providers.
>
> If you do not manage your own server or if you are using shared
>   hosting, contact your server administrator or hosting provider to make
>   sure that you are protected against this vulnerability.

**If I'm managing server myself then what I have to do?**

**If it's shared hosting then what I have to tell Server Administrator?**

Answer (score 1):

This is to do with your server OS and not Magento. Security patches are still being released.

If you manage your own server, you will need to get (or wait) for the patch. Patches have not been released for all Linux versions yet but I would expect within the month. Your hosting provider and the OS website will have more answers for you. It may be that your hosting provider can still help you even though you have managed hosting.

If you use shared hosting, open a ticket with your host and tell them your concerns re Dirty COW (CVE-2016-5195). Good hosts will already be working on a solution or getting the patch update.